# What is causing this warning in Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino-uno, library

I'm using [DS3231 module](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS3231.pdf) with [rinkydink library](http://www.rinkydinkelectronics.com/library.php?id=73) and it is working just fine, however every time i want to compile the code Arduino IDE shows this warning:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\DS3231\DS3231.cpp:291:106:
warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*'
[-Wwrite-strings]
```

What is this warning and how to solve it?

Comment: You're passing a string constant to a function that expects a variable.

Comment: But often it's library writer's mistake and that parameter could (and should) be `const` because there is no write access to it.

Comment: why do you use this old library?

Comment: On the face of it your argument sounds fine.  But looking at the nuts and bolts of why a const is used makes it a bit more obvious why this is a warning.  When a compiler encounters a const, it might try putting that value into (read only) program memory.  After all, you promised not to change it.  But passing it as a formal value may be interpreted as you wanting to create a variable in the called to function.  So there can be confusion or a disconnect in what the compiler does and what you expect to happen.

Comment: Before giving up, try passing a pointer to the const.  Let me know if that works and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @st2000, for Uno compiler doesn't put const into progmem. the problem is inside a library OP uses, so they don't do anything to cause this warning

Comment: @st2000 i don't know how to do it, sorry i'm very new to this... post an answer and if it can solve the warning i'll make it the correct answer.

Comment: I have started building up a list of common errors and their explanations: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/common-arduino-errors-and-warnings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning was caused by this line:

```cpp
char *monthShort[] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
```

In C++, the content of a character string such as `"Jan"` cannot be
modified. Thus, if you assign the string to a pointer, the pointer
should be declared as **const** char *:

```cpp
const char *monthShort[] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                            "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
```

The same applies to the other arrays of strings: `daysLong`, `daysShort`
and `monthLong`. As a consequence, the prototypes of the methods
`getDOWStr()` and `getMonthStr()` should be changed in order to return a
`const char *`.

BTW, are you sure this library is still maintained? This should have
been fixed a long time ago, and it seems the source was last modified in
2015. You may be better off using a more modern alternative. For
instance, in the Arduino library manager, you can find [DS3231](https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/ds3231) and
Adafruit's [RTClib](https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/rt-clib).

Comment: i use this library because i'm very new to arduino and everyone every where suggested this and it's easy to use, i'll try the new libraries. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The DS3231 library from Rinky Dink is the best RTC library there is...I know, I tried them ALL.  This library allows one to print date and time strings with only 3 Arduino print statements:  Serial.print(rtc.getDateStr());
      Serial.print(" -- ");
      Serial.println(rtc.getTimeStr());
Other RTC libraries force user to make the strings up themselves, at a cost of about 12 lines of useless Serial.print commands.